# How to make <p> within "jumbotron" responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm pretty new to coding and just working on familiarizing myself with html/css/bootstrap. The

element in my "jumbotron" class doesn't resize correctly when I change the size of the screen (it all piles on top of each other). See it here: http://www.bohmerconstruction.com/test.html/ . If you resize the screen to a lower width, you'll see what the

element does. This is also how it shows up on mobile.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Let us help you</h1>
    <p><a href="http://www.bohmerconstruction.com/contact-bohmer-construction.html">Contact us for your free estimate</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: url('http://constructotal.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ist2_5357604-construction-background-1024x680.jpg');
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
}


.jumbotron h1 {
color: white;
margin-top: 95px;
float: left;
height: 100%;

}

.jumbotron p {
font-size:18px;
margin-top: 180px;
margin-right: 480px;
height:100%;

}


.jumbotron a {
color: #297ACC;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Instead of linking to a page that you are redoing, please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead. That way it stays the same even after you change your test site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to do the work of the text align. The margin right is what is hurting you. However let's get rid of that float so you do not have to set a margin top on your **p** element.

**Replace** these declarations

```
.jumbotron p {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

and

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 95px;
    text-align: left;
}
```